# Giving planets quirks - How can I make the planets in my solar system interesting, even if they're relatively normal?

Tags: planets, science-fiction, space

My question is simple: what are ways that I can give planets their own unique features without going too crazy? So far, I've created 3 planets: one that has crazy volcanic activity, one that is relatively hot and yet lush with flora and fauna, and one that has the crust of the planet covered by an ocean. Obviously, those last two are a bit on the extreme side, so I'm trying to next make a planet that is interesting but not wackily so. My first step was to make the surface of the planet covered in a sand that is purple thanks to the mineral content of the sand being rich in grains of amethyst and garnet.

Are there any good quirks that I can give planets that aren't too unique? Anything with geography, planetary composition, radiation, weather, etc. will work. Thanks a ton, and sorry if this is the wrong place to ask this.

Comment: Welcome to worldbuilding. What makes something interesting is a total matter of opinion: one of my professor at the University used to go touring to photograph rusting metal structures. Opinion based questions are a poor fit here. Check the [help] for more info.

Comment: To a lot of us, only "relatively normal" planets would be interesting.

Comment: As the others have mentioned, this question is quite open ended currently. I would suggest asking more targeted questions that hit specific aspects of uniqueness that you are interested in, to crib your idea, sometying like "How can I have a planet covered in sand of each colour of the rainbow?"

Comment: Like Kyyshak said, try to come up with ideas, (looking through "exoplanets" or "sci-fi planets" on an image search may give you ideas, as well as some tags on Worldbuilding like "planets" or "environment).  Once you have an idea of what you want a planet or system to look like, this is a great place to ask the "is this realistic?" or "How can I make this happen?" questions.

Comment: R0yal it looks like this is going to be closed.  Dutch's comment is a good one.  Maybe you could edit this to clarify the reason you are inventing your planets.  If it is because you are a painter and wish to paint exotic planentscapes, interesting planets might be different from what you need for a role playing game to keep players interested, or as homeworlds for the alien characters in your fiction story.  What are you up to, R0?